# Macro to search through a column (user input) for specific characters, then put (user input) text into adjacent column

Tags: vba, excel

Good morning / afternoon / evening, everyone.

I have a very strange problem and VBA isn't exactly my best language. So I want to take user input for some ingredient (all of the ingredients are in the format "2 INGREDIENT NAME ................" with a variable number of periods (wasn't my idea haha).

So I want to search column B (where the ingredients are) for some ingredient given user input (for example, I want a text box to ask for input, and for example if I type in "CMC" I want it to find the cells containing "CMC") and when it finds the input, I want it to write a code for it (a second text input box) into column A adjacent to it.

So in short I have 2 input boxes, one I put CMC into, and the other some code, let's say 5555. Then I want it to search for all instances of cells containing CMC in column B and then write the corresponding code on Column A of the same row.

I'm completely stumped by this. Any help would be appreciated! My Code:

```
Function Test()

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Dim myValue As String
myValue = InputBox("Enter Recipe Name")
Dim ItemN As String
ItemN = InputBox("Enter Recipe CODE")




//I put this into column A?//
For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1
IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("*myValue*",B:B,1)),"","ItemN")

End If
Next i







End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This?

```
Function Test()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim myValue As String
    Dim ItemN As String
    Dim i As Integer

    'your data is supposed to be in a sheet named "Data"
    LastRow = Worksheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    myValue = InputBox("Enter Recipe Name")
    ItemN = InputBox("Enter Recipe CODE")

    For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1
        If (InStr(Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 2), myValue) And Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 2) <> "") Then
            Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 1) = ItemN
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you! A few questions if you don't mind. the cell i,2 doesn't = myValue, but rather will contain myValue. Can I use a predefined excel function to check if it contains the value? Also if I made this a sub macro would that work? That way I can just run it, put values in, and it'll just run for all instances of that word?                                                             The Cells are formatted like                                                                     "  2           CMC  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . "

Comment: For example could I do something like:                                                          If (Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 2).ISNUMBER(SEARCH("CMC",B:B,1))= True ) ?

Comment: Can't properly understand you. First of all, have you tried the code? That would be a good starting point. And then, the line `If (Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 2) = myValue) Then` is not assigning a value to cell(i,2), but checking if its value equals the variable `myValue`. Also, in its current form, it will add `ItemN` in each instance of `myValue`. And finally, you can add a command button (for example), and place the code inside `Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()` or similar, so code will run every time you press the button.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for helping me out. I really do appreciate it. Sorry VBA isn't exactly my strong suit. I tried the code and it works very well if the myValue is exactly identical. For example if I replace the "2 CMC .............." with just the "CMC" then it works perfectly. So the way I understand it is: I would need to either use a function to check if the cell contains the word (IE. CMC) or make a new column that takes all the filler out of the cell and transforms it into just the ingredient since I won't be typing in "2 ingredient............" for every ingredient.

Comment: I was thinking something like:    If (Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 2).Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Application.WorksheetFunction.Search("MyValue")) = True) Then

Comment: Yes, it work if values are identical. I didn't understand the "contain" part. Replace `If (Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 2) = myValue) Then` with `If (InStr(myValue, Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 2))) Then`. I would not use `IsNumber` for comparing string. At least it would not be my first option.

Comment: With that replacement it fills all Blank cells in column A that correspond with a blank column B with the code instead of the cell adjacent to the ingredient. Any reason why?

Comment: Glad I could help.